# "quarkus dev" throws FileNotFoundException looking for a specific maven version at an URL that does not exist

Tags: quarkus

When launching my project with using `quarkus dev` I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.8.1/apache-maven-3.9.0-bin.zip
> at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1989)
> at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1585)
> at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
> at org.apache.maven.wrapper.DefaultDownloader.downloadInternal(DefaultDownloader.java:90)
> at org.apache.maven.wrapper.DefaultDownloader.download(DefaultDownloader.java:76)
> at org.apache.maven.wrapper.Installer.createDist(Installer.java:72)
> at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:121)
> at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:61)

However, when using `mvn quarkus:dev`, my app loads normally.

**`quarkus dev` used to work with this project**. Why is it looking for this particular URL?

Update: The same happens with `quarkus update`.

Although `quarkus version` works

I already reinstalled quarkus CLI (with Chocolatey)

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was the property `distributionUrl` in maven-wrapper.properties.
For some reason, the version of the file did not match the version of the parent folder